# How can I use my static CSS with VueJS and webpack

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-4

I’m struggling a little with webpack, VUE and my CSS static files. See, I’d like to inject the styles that are in the Single File Components with the  and I also want to have my static CSS file that has some useful classes. I’m running webpack 4 and I don’t clearly know how to approach the static CSS file situation.
This is my webpack config so far:

```js
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const makeConfig = (mode) => require(`./build-utils/webpack.${mode}.js`)(mode)
const MiniCss = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = (env) => {
    return WebpackMerge.merge(
        {
            mode: env.mode,
            entry: './src/main.js',
            output: {
                filename: '[name].js',
                publicPath: '/',
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.vue$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        loader: 'vue-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(js)$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        use: [
                            { loader: 'babel-loader' }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(css)/,
                        use: [
                            MiniCss.loader,
                            'css-loader'
                        ],
                        include: /\assets\.css$/ 
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(css)/,
                        use: [
                            'style-loader',
                            'css-loader'
                        ],
                        exclude: /\assets\.css$/,
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'file-loader',
                                options: {
                                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                                    esModule: false
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            plugins: [
                new VueLoaderPlugin(),
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                    template: 'index.html'
                }),
                new MiniCss()
            ]
        },
        makeConfig(env.mode)
    )    
}
```

I have my statics css under /src/assets. Then my CSS assets gets imported in the entry point javascript’s file. The problem is that I don’t get my static CSS file emitted. What’s the solution for both: have my static css and the Single Component CSS.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, my approach is to import your static css in the style section of your `App.vue` component: `<style lang="css">@import "./assets/styles.css";</style>`
In the webpack configuration I would import css variables. Do you have css-variables or plain css-code?

Comment: It's plain CSS for now but I think I'll move to SASS. Nice approach I'll try It.

Comment: Does it work for you?